# Why I cant click on rows of this table in html?

Tags: php, html, jquery, datatable, row

I have a dynamic table which I populate with data fetched from my db using PHP. 
I tried following some tutorials and I could see that in their fiddle it was working but why doesn't it work on mine?

Could it be related to the scripts and links I am importing?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable').dataTable({
            initComplete: function() {
                this.api().columns().every(function() {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select  class="browser-default custom-select form-control-sm"><option value="" selected>Filter</option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                        .on('change', function() {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );
                            column
                                .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                .draw();
                        });
                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
            var data = table.row(this).data();
        });
    });

    $('#myTable tr').each(function() {
        // need this to skip the first row
        if ($(this).find("td:first").length > 0) {
            var cutomerId = $(this).find("td:first").html();
        }
    });
</script>
```

and the table below:

```
 <table id="myTable" class="display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Report ID</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Case</th>                   
                <th>Date received</th>                  
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php if (!empty($show_arr)) { ?>
                <?php foreach ($show_arr as $user) {
                    if ($user['display'] == 1) {
                ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo '<a href=selectedReport.php?rep_id=' . urlencode($user["id"]) . "&cus_id=" . urlencode($user["cus_id"]) . "&name=" . urlencode($user["name"]) . '>' . $user["id"] . '</a>'; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo '<a href=selectedReport.php?cus_id=' . urlencode($user["cus_id"]) . "&rep_id=" . urlencode($user["id"]) . "&name=" . urlencode($user["name"]) . "&state=" . urlencode($user["state"]) . '>' . $user["name"] . '(' . $user["username"] . ')</a>'; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php
                                echo '<a href=selectedReport.php?cus_id=' . urlencode($user["cus_id"]) . "&rep_id=" . urlencode($user["id"]) . "&name=" . urlencode($user["name"]) . "&state=" . urlencode($user["state"]) . '>' . $user['report_cases_accepted'][0]['case_id'] . '</a>';
                                ?>
                            </td>                             

                            <td>
                                <?php
                                echo $user['date_sent'];
                                ?>
                            </td>                               

                        </tr>
            <?php
                    }
                }
            } ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>                    
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

My intention is to be able to click in rows and get the data you see in PHP and then redirect to another page. Basically, I want to do exactly the same what I am doing below using `a href...` but without it, now I just want to click anywhere in the rows, take the values of that row and redirect to next page.
Please let me know if there you see something wrong with the code above. My doubts are somewhere in the way I am importing the scripts and stylesheets but I am not sure.

Comment: _"...but why doesn't it work on mine?"_ - That's not really a error description... Why do you think it _"doesn't work"_?

Comment: Have you made sure that `$('#example tbody')` exists? (Because your table has `id="myTable"`)

Comment: @Andreas I already stated why I think it doesn't work but I dont know for sure if I am right about that.

Comment: There's still no hint on why you think it doesn't work. No _"my event handler isn't executed, which I've tested by adding a `console.log(...)`/tested by stepping through it with the debugger/..."_, _"there's this error thrown in the console: ..."_, ...